# getting this error while Parsing SOAP Webservice in Android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap

```
04-14 22:09:40.158: E/REQUEST=(274): Authenticate{Username=lll; }
04-14 22:09:40.158: E/SOAP ENVOLP=(274): **envolpe=org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@43e5b748
04-14 22:09:43.799: W/System.err(274): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT 
04-14 22:09:43.799: W/System.err(274): Warning: DOMXPa...@27:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e6ec48)** 
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1420)
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:90)
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:179)
04-14 22:09:43.819: W/System.err(274):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at com.dev.coaster.SignIn.onClick(SignIn.java:71)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 22:09:43.829: W/System.err(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 22:09:43.839: W/System.err(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 22:09:43.839: W/System.err(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-14 22:09:43.839: W/System.err(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-14 22:09:43.839: W/System.err(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**04-14 22:09:43.839: E/SOAP Result=(274): result=null**
```

And My Code for SOAP parsing is:-

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
 request.addProperty("Username","lll");

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 envelope.dotNet = true;
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            Log.e("REQUEST=",""+request);
            Log.e("SOAP ENVOLP=","envolpe="+envelope);
            // Make the soap call.
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {

                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);        

                getResult = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.       
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

              Log.e("SOAP Result=","result="+result);
```

Comment: i need urgent and please sugest me

Comment: Error says Xml String you received is not Well-Formed (i see error is nested inside parseResponse Method). Give a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928759/android-with-wcf-web-service-using-ksoap2-error-soapfault-faultcode-ainte/12955665#12955665. Use Log method to see what is your real request and real response you receive

Comment: Log.e("SOAP Result=","result="+result); is null

Comment: private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://demo.rimits.com/costerAppService/";
 private static String NAMESPACE = "http://demo.rimits.com/costerAppService/";
 private static String METHOD_NAME = "Authenticate";
 private static String URL = "http://demo.rimits.com/costerAppService/Server_Soap.php";
i am tryind parsing form these web services please sugest me

Comment: It seems response is wrong for some reason (with "wrong" i mean xml string response is not well-formed). Probably on server side. You have to understand what happens on server side while it takes your Soap Request. You have to see how server handles it

Comment: kinghomer Can you please chack this webservice and reply me i am new in SOAP and need urgent

Comment: I saw WebService and Authentication method need password property too. In your example you are adding only username property. If method requires 2 parameters, you have to specify 2 property

Comment: Wait, Authentication method requires complex object! One property called "Authenticate" and 2 nested properties called "Username" and "Password". You have to create a complex object for nesting properties inside a root property. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805946/nesting-properties-inside-a-tag-in-ksoap2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication method requires complex object! 
One property called "Authenticate" and 2 nested properties called "Username" and "Password". You have to create a complex object for nesting properties inside a root property. Take a look here:
[Nesting properties inside a tag in Ksoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805946/nesting-properties-inside-a-tag-in-ksoap2)