# KSOAP2 request body format issue

Tags: java, android, xml, wsdl, ksoap2

I have a service activated in SAP ECC 6.0 which i am successfully able to test from SOAP UI 5 which generates following SOAP REQUEST

**Request Generated by SOAPUI 5.0 Working Successfully**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:glob="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <glob:PurchaseOrderItemByAccountAssignmentQuery_sync>
         <PurchaseOrderItemSelectionByAccountAssignment>
            <PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID schemeID="?" schemeAgencyID="?">15001030000600</PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID>
         </PurchaseOrderItemSelectionByAccountAssignment>
      </glob:PurchaseOrderItemByAccountAssignmentQuery_sync>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However when i call this service from KSOAP2 API using following code i am not able to get correct response instead i get element missing error.

**Code (android based) generating faulty request**

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global";
private static String URL = "http://sapqas.trkl.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/xip/sap/ecc_purchaseorder003qr/330/abcdef/abcdef_binding";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "PurchaseOrderItemByAccountAssignmentQuery_sync";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();

propInfo.setName("PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID");
propInfo.setType(String.class);
propInfo.setValue("15001030000600");
request.addProperty(propInfo);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
List <HeaderProperty> headerPropertyList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerPropertyList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic bsadasdWxpsadasdZmNAsadaNA=="));

envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

try {

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headerPropertyList);
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            } catch (SoapFault e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainlayoutActivity.this,
                        e.faultcode + " Error : 0" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(MainlayoutActivity.this,
                        e.getStatusCode() + " Error : 1" + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(MainlayoutActivity.this,
                        "Error : 2" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(MainlayoutActivity.this,
                        e.getLineNumber() + "Error : 3" + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainlayoutActivity.this,
                        "Error : 4" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

The soap request generated by my code is below which has an element missing but i am not sure how to add it to my request using KSOAP2 API.

**Request created by Above Code**

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:PurchaseOrderItemByAccountAssignmentQuery_sync id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
<PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID>15001030000600</PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID>
</n0:PurchaseOrderItemByAccountAssignmentQuery_sync>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>

Error from Web Service: (CX_ST_GROUP_MISSING_CASE)
```

**Required**

I want to add  tag from first request to be added in my soap request but not able to do so.

**Additional Information:**

below "PurchaseOrderItemSelectionByAccountAssignment" tag there could be multiple parameters but i am only using "PurchaseOrderItemAccountAssignmentCostCentreID" parameter.

Anyone has idea where i am going wrong and how to change it to create right soap request?

regards,

Comment: you are posting data on xml formate or json?

Comment: i am posting data through XML, XML is being generated by the code i have pasted above using KSOAP2 API

Comment: Problem resolved by using this link on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805946/nesting-properties-inside-a-tag-in-ksoap2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved using the kvmserialization interface implementation as discussed in the link below.

This was essentially a case of implementing complex types.

Lesson Learnt : if you face an issue creating / parsing soap request or response please map your WSDL and its contents with the KSOAP API you shall find an answer after doing some research.

[Nesting properties inside a tag in Ksoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805946/nesting-properties-inside-a-tag-in-ksoap2)

Comment: Can you share some more light on creating the SOAP request body. And Mapping the WSDL with the KSOAP API