# Web services cannot interprete properties

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I am trying this for add data into Soap manager to accessing web-services into my project.

```
 PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.name="userid";
        unameProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        unameProp.setNamespace(NAME_SPACE);
        unameProp.setValue(UserId); /*add your value here*/
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable, this will set your value in arg0.

        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.name="password";
        passwordProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        passwordProp.setNamespace(NAME_SPACE);
        passwordProp.setValue(Password); /*add your value here*/
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(true);
```

Here is my WSDL file format

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://noobsol.com/tickr">
<s:element name="UserLogin">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserId" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="UserLoginResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserLoginResult">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

After accessing this code ,i got this value into my log cat

```
response anyType{ErrorCode=1; ErrorMessage=Incorrect Username or Password; UserId=anyType{}; Password=anyType{}; }
```

This is the result,I am getting from web service .User Id & Password fields are exactly return by the web service just for debugging.

I have tried various answers available on SO, to no avail. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 'UserId'... check the caps... u´re using 'userId'

Comment: same for password, I´m afraid...

Comment: I have tried that earlier.

Comment: yup yup... Use the same name and nest your properties following the SOAP structure such as they do in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805946/nesting-properties-inside-a-tag-in-ksoap2

Comment: @eduyayo - 
I got this result androidHttpTransport.requestDump = <userId i:type="d:string">maneen</userId><password i:type="d:string">123456</password> and androidHttpTransport.responseDump=<ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode><ErrorMessage>Incorrec‌​t Username or Password</ErrorMessage><UserId></UserId><Password></Password> So, I want userid & password on responsedump.........if u knw it......help us....

Comment: First, you´ve got he userId still not in caps. Second, you have to construct the message following 'UserLogin' with two nested properties: 'UserId' and  'Password'. You can see how they nest properties in the link I´ve posted before

Comment: @eduyayo - When I am used your example code request & response value is null.So,nested properties not work properly...

Comment: could you post your code, please?

Comment: @eduyayo-My new question

Soap method is not accepting any input parameter.
Here I am defining my code.